# Glyph names and GeneralPath in Apache FontBox (PDFBox)

Tags: java, apache, path, pdfbox, glyph

I am using Apache FontBox to get the font metrics. I get a GeneralPath from a glyph and from there I get some information like the height of a glyph.

I am trying to get a GeneralPath object from the name of the glyph in an OpenType font. If I use this form, I get accurate glyph information (path).

```
GeneralPath glyphPath = otfFont.getPath("uni24C8");
System.out.println(glyphPath.getBounds2D().getMaxY()); //Ok...
```

However, if I try to get the glyph name from the Unicode code, I get incorret information for the glyph:

```
int glyphID = otfFont.getUnicodeCmap().getGlyphId(0x0075);
String name = otfFont.getCFF().getFont().getCharset().getNameForGID(glyphID);
GeneralPath glyphPath = otfFont.getPath(name);
System.out.println(glyphPath.getBounds2D().getMaxY()); //Incorrect...
```

In fact, FontBox can not find the glyph that matches the given name. For example, the following call returns false.

```
otfFont.hasGlyph(otfFont.getCFF().getFont().getCharset().getNameForGID(glyphID));
```

What am I doing wrong?
Whenever I use directly names like "uni0075" or "uni24C8", I get correct values. But I do not know how to get these names from the GlyphId.

Ps.: otfFont is a object OpenTypeFont.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Just replace the following call:

```
GeneralPath glyphPath = otfFont.getPath(name);
```

for this:

```
GeneralPath glyphPath = otfFont.getCFF().getFont().getPath(name);
```

This solves my problem with the OpenType font I'm using.